# how to filter two sets of keyvalue pairs for differences using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of KeyValue pairs which I want to filter.

I would like to retrieve the keyvalue pairs from list B if the value is different to the key value in list A.

```
List A      List B 
<a,1>       <b,4>
<b,2>       <c,5>
<c,3>
```

so if I filter the above two key value pair lists I would get the following:

```
List c
<b,4>
<c,5>
```

is this possible without having to use a foreach loop and checking individual key values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join both lists by keys, then select those items, which have different values:

```
from kvpA in listA
join kvpB in listB on kvpA.Key equals kvpB.Key
where kvpA.Value != kvpB.Value
select kvpB
```

Lambda syntax:

```
listA.Join(listB, 
           kvpA => kvpA.Key, 
           kvpB => kvpB.Key, 
           (kvpA, kvpB) => new { kvpA, kvpB })
     .Where(x => x.kvpA.Value != x.kvpB.Value)
     .Select(x => x.kvpB)
     .ToList()
```

Comment: hi, can you provide the lambda syntax for this also?

Comment: @xerxes: Did you try converting it to lambda syntax yourself? Always try to do things yourself and ask for help when you get stuck, rather than just asking for people to do things for you.

Comment: @xerxes I don't like how lambda syntax with joins looks like, but sure it can be done with lambdas. Also agree with Jon, always try to do things by yourself before ask, if you want to grow as programmer

Comment: sorry, I haven't used the sugar syntax before so I really am clueless in regards to converting it into the lambda format, but thank you for the solution.

Comment: @xerxes I suggest you to spend some time investigating sugar syntax - it's easier to use and understand (thus it's declarative). And one note - you can select anonymous type which has key and both values from lists: `select new { Key = kvpA.Key, A = kvpA.Value, B = kvpB.Value }` maybe that will be useful

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
ListB.Where(kvpB => !ListA.Select(kvpA => kvpA.Value).Contains(kvpB.Value))
```